# Using JavaScript to Store Request Payload to localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, local-storage

After submitting a form on a website, in Google Chrome's dev console there is an XHR request of application/json type that posts data to another server.

The POST request contains a JSON array and I'm trying to grab one of those parameters and store it in localStorage or sessionStorage for later use.

Is it possible to do this using only JavaScript on the front-end?  I'm thinking along the lines...when the request url is http://example.com/service, then grab the JSON object and select the 'name' element and set to key 'name' in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Global Ajax Event Handlers" from jquery:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.url === 'http://example.com/service') {
    // do your processing - grab JSON (from XHR) and store it to localstorage
  }
});
```

Or you can also patch XMLHttpRequest manually:

```
(function() {

    var proxied = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        console.log(arguments);

        if (arguments[1].indexOf('/service') > -1) {
          // do your processing
        }

        return proxied.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    };

})();
```

Comment: I was thinking of ajaxComplete, but I'm stuck using only pure JavaScript.  That's where I don't know how to grab the JSON from the XHR request.

Comment: You can also use XMLHttpRequest directly for that (globally), updated the answer